# bubblesort function in python 3

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I'm trying to understand how bubbleset works.  I know there are multiple threads about this here but they are all different versions of the function and don't do a good job explaining to a newbie. I found this succinct code for a bubblesort on youtube:

```
def bubblesort(mylist):
for i in range(0, len(mylist) - 1):
    for j in range(0, len(mylist) - 1 - i):
        if mylist[j] > mylist[j+1]:
            mylist[j], mylist[j+1] = mylist[j+1], mylist[j]
return mylist
```

can someone explain to me the purpose of line 3 where it says len(mylist) - 1 - i? Why are we subtracting i? what does mylist do?

I'm a beginner programmer, just trying to get a better understanding on how these loops are working.

Comment: This website is a great way of understanding sorting algorithms https://visualgo.net/sorting

Comment: this is a non-optimal implementation ...

Comment: so what would be a optimal implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because after each iteration, the last number is sorted. To elaborate, let's look at this list:

```
[0, 2, 5, 7, 3, 1]
```

After the first sort, the largest number will be sorted. After the second sort, the second-largest number has been sorted. Or basically, the number at the index `len(myList ) - 1 - iteration` will be sorted already and will be at the correct position. After the first sort, the largest number is in place. The largest number's index is now at `len(myList) - 1`. Then the second largest number will be placed correctly, this `iteration` goes from 0 to 1 so the second largest number's index is now `len(myList) - 1 - iteration` or `len(myList) - 1 - 1` which is right before the largest number.

Comment: ok, so i would be the iteration number.  so for each iteration that number is increased by 1? because that last number has already been sorted, so we leave it out of the next iteration, so eventually it will just end up at index 0 and terminate?

Comment: @RyanPostell Remember to click the green checkmark by the answer you feel was the best answer to your problem